# Maven : could not resolve dependencies on J2EE project

Tags: maven

I am trying to package my JEE application with Maven.
I am getting this error:

```
 Failed to execute goal on project xxx: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxx.xxx:xxx:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.0.0 ->
 org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:0.9.7.309-JS-3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:0.9.7.309-JS-3: Could not transfer artifact org.olap4j:olap4j:pom:0.9.7.309-JS-3 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/
): Blocked mirror for repositories: [jasperreports (http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2, default, releases+snapshots), jaspersoft-third-party (http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/, default, releases+snapshots)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project xxx: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxx.xxx:xxx:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.0.0 -> org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:0.9.7.309-JS-3
```

[image]
[image]

I do have this library in my repo :
[image]

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: problem: `Blocked mirror for repositories: [jasperreports (http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2, default, releases+snapshots)` is the problem!!!

Comment: I m new with maven. Having the library in the repo locally shoudn't be enough? it needs to go to http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2?  If so, how could I solve this?

Comment: Solved it by updating settings.xml file mirror section (I commented the mirror section)